# Use google as a search engine or a custom search engine

Tags: php, search-engine, google-search

This is my site: [My Site](http://ankursinha.net/TestSite/)

I want to know for the search bar placed in the site (made with Bootstrap), do I code and make a search engine myself (I know how to do that, I don't think I need help on that) or do I use Google to search within my website and give results in my website itself in the body of the container by retaining the header and footer. I have seen my University website search engine is powered by google.

If the latter is a good option, then am I allowed to do that? Is it free in the first place? Some claim it is free while some claim it's not. So I want to get it clarified.

I only have user profiles stored, very soon I might have some notifications, announcements, blogs, faqs, etc. in my database. So the data is not that huge or anything but it's somewhat big.

Comment: is this the sort of thing you're after? http://www.google.co.uk/enterprise/search/products_gss.html

Comment: Can I also know the reason for the downvote so that I will know what I haven't done and where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

- Google "Google CSE"
- Sign up for it
- Give all the information they ask for
- Try out difference templates and styles and check what suits you

If you want your own search engine, implementing it would be hard because you are new to it, and with content being added every now and then you might have to update things in the form of keywords. So Google is a good option.